# Find Taylor series for these related series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I want to find the Taylor series of:

$$\frac{1}{(3-z)^2}$$

so it sort of looks like this:

$$\frac{1}{(3-z)} = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{(1 - \frac{z}{3})} = \frac{1}{3} (1 + \frac{z}{3} + \frac{z^2}{9} + ...)  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{3^{n+1}}$$

Can I take the derivative? But what can I take the derivative of?

I am told the answer is:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{nz^{n-1}}{3^{n+1}}$$ but I'm not sure how to get there?

Comment: It seems like you did the hard part. The derivative of $(3-z)^{-1}$ is $(3-z)^{-2}$, and this equals the series obtained by differentiating the Taylor series term by term.

Comment: So isn't the derivative of $\frac{1}{(3 - z)} = \frac{-(-1)}{(e-z)^2}$...

Comment: Oh wait... the derivative of $\frac{z^n}{(3^{n+1})} = \frac{nz^{n-1} \cdot 3^{n+1} - (0)}{(3^{n+1})^2}$ right? If so, I am dumb

Comment: You are over complicating all of your derivatives. By chain rule, $\frac{d}{dz} (3-z)^{-1}=-(3-z)^{-2}\frac{d}{dz}(3-z)=(3-z)^{-2}$. For the other derivative, you are just differentiating $z^n$ times a constant. Also, by the way, in the answer, the sum should start at $n=1$ after differentiating.

Comment: Oh I see, so I can just take the derivative of the part in front of the $\sum$ and that's the answer since we already showed that derivative of $(3-z)^{-1} = (3-z)^{-2}$

Comment: That's the idea. I mean, technically speaking, it does require some mathematical analysis to show that bringing the derivative operator inside the series is justified.  Technically, we only know that the derivative of a finite sum is the sum of the derivatives (hence, term by term differentiation). This also holds for Taylor series in the limit.

Comment: Where do we know this from? IT seems correct but from where is this theorem derived?

Comment: Wanan give me a full answer and I'll give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea behind why differentiation term by term is justified:

The series $f(z)=\frac 13\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{z}{3} \right)^n$ has radius of convergence $R=3$.  This means the series converges absolutely when $|z|<3$. Take any $z$ with $|z|<3$. Then there exists $r>0$ such that $|z|\leq r <3$. Then by the Weierstrass M-test, we have
$$
\left|\frac{z}{3} \right|^n\leq \left(\frac{r}{3} \right)^n
$$
so $f_N(z)=\frac 13\sum_{n=0}^N \left(\frac{z}{3} \right)^n$ converges to $f(z)$ uniformly and absolutely. Similar methods show that $f_N'$ converges uniformly.

Finally, the uniform convergence of $f_N \to f$ and $f_N'$ to some function for $|z|\leq r$ guarantees that
$$
f'(z)=\lim_{N\to \infty} f_N'(z).
$$
In other words, we can bring the derivative operator inside.